# Firefox download popup still persists after profile setting in Selenium

Tags: selenium, firefox, profile

After setting up a profile for running tests in Firefox, I set the download popups to false but am still seeing it upon running my tests.  Here is the profile I am setting up:

```
        switch (browser){
        case "FFX": 
            System.out.println("Starting test in FireFox");
            try {
                driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //TODO Create a system properties file in case driver location moves.
            break;

    ...
    public static FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile() throws Exception {

    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);        
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.animateNotifications", false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);     
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", downloadPath);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",
            "text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/"
            + "png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml");
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
            "text/csv,application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,image/"
            + "png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml");
    //  ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    //  firefoxProfile = profile.getProfile("selenium");

    return firefoxProfile;
```

But I am still getting this window:

[image: test]

Am I missing an entry for my profile settings?  I thought it would be:

```
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
```

EDIT:  I have added more to this, How I am setting up my driver and how I am building my profile.  I also added the commented out part where I simply just assign a profile "selenium" to the driver.  Currently what happens is the driver starts up as if it was just ran "out of the box" fresh install every single time.  It only adheres to the setPreferences (or almost all of them) and completely ignores any custom profile I set up in advance.  The ongoing download confirmation notification is really what is killing my tests here.  Any ideas or observations are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Once you run the selenium code, you can manually check if the preference is getting set properly by typing '*about:config*' in Firefox url bar. Also, try toggling **browser.download.animateNotifications** to **false** on the about:config page. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work I'm afraid.  I'd love to just use a custom profile but Firefox seems to be ignoring my custom profile and using a default one for some reason.  That would make this whole thing so easy.

Comment: Try creating FireFox profile(testProfile) manually and use that profile while initiating the driver. `ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
 
FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("testProfile");
 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);` You can refer [CustomFFProfile](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/) link.

Comment: I believe I did that already (Look at the last 2 commented out lines of the code I pasted). Unless I am mistaken.  I did create one specific to selenium and tried to use that but the driver seems to ignore it.  It only uses "out of the box" or "default" settings.

Comment: Does it happen even if you set your "selenium" profile as default profile for launching Firefox?

Comment: 6  I'm not sure what you mean.  If you are referring to "open this profile when firefox opens" checkbox then yes it happens even then.  It acts like its using another firefox somewhere but Ive scoured the entire computer and found nothing.  Im not connected to a network where it could grab an install from somewhere else either.

Comment: Yes! I was referring to "open this profile when firefox opens". That did the trick for me.

Comment: I gave that a try and it didn't do anything different than load an out of the box default.